# How to deactivate bool var if nothing is pressed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem in my code. I have a sprite and when I click on it I rotate another object. That object i can move it left, right with the keyboard. The problem is that if you keep pressing LeftArrow and at the same time click to rotate it then the object continues to move to the left even if you do not click on anything.

```
private KeyboardEventSystem kBoard;
private Dictionary<KeyCode, bool> pressed = new Dictionary<KeyCode, bool>();
[ReadOnly] public bool moving;
[ReadOnly] public bool grounded = false;

void Start()
{
    degeticaRb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    kBoard = gameObject.AddComponent<KeyboardEventSystem>();
    kBoard.addKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow);
    kBoard.addKey(KeyCode.RightArrow);
    kBoard.addMap(KeyCode.A, KeyCode.LeftArrow);
    kBoard.addMap(KeyCode.D, KeyCode.RightArrow);
    pressed.Add(KeyCode.LeftArrow, false);
    pressed.Add(KeyCode.RightArrow, false);
    kBoard.KeyBoardEvent += KBoard_KeyBoardEvent;
}

private void KBoard_KeyBoardEvent(KeyboardEventType keyboardEventType, KeyCode keyCode)
{
    if (!grounded)
        return;

    if (keyboardEventType == KeyboardEventType.DOWN)
        pressed[keyCode] = true;
    if (keyboardEventType == KeyboardEventType.UP)
    {
        moving = false;
        pressed[keyCode] = false;
        degeticaRb.angularVelocity = 0f;
        degeticaRb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
    }
}

public void DoRotation(int tIndex)
{
    Vector3 rotAngle = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
    if (tIndex == 1)
    {
        rotAngle.z -= 90f;
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x - 0.65f, transform.position.y);
    }
    else
    {
        rotAngle.z += 90f;
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + 0.65f, transform.position.y);
    }
    transform.eulerAngles = rotAngle;
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(Feet.position, 0.1f);
    grounded = false;
    foreach (Collider2D coll in colliders)
    {
        if (coll.tag == "wall")
        {
            grounded = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        moving = (pressed[KeyCode.LeftArrow] ^ pressed[KeyCode.RightArrow]);
        if (moving && grounded)
        {
            moveAxis += pressed[KeyCode.RightArrow] ? accelaration : (accelaration * -1f);
            moveAxis = Mathf.Clamp(moveAxis, -1, 1);
            degeticaRb.velocity = new Vector2(moveAxis * moveSpeed, degeticaRb.velocity.y);
        }
        else
            moveAxis = 0f;

    }
    else
        moving = false;
    DoMoveAnim();
}
```

So the bool variable `moving` remains active even if I do not press on anything. Help!

Comment: You could step through your code and see where `moving` turns into `true`.

Comment: moving = (pressed[KeyCode.LeftArrow] ^ pressed[KeyCode.RightArrow]) && canMove;

Comment: only here.......

Comment: canMove i put it now

Comment: It seems a curious way to handle keyboard events, however, one important factor, if for whatever reason it feels you are not grounded when the key is released it will remain true..... forever..#

Comment: yes, but I deactivate the key:  pressed[keyCode] = false;

Comment: when i release keyboard

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage your key states even if the object isn't grounded. The only things that care if it's grounded is setting `moving = false` and setting the velocities to zero:

```
private void KBoard_KeyBoardEvent(KeyboardEventType keyboardEventType, KeyCode keyCode)
{
    if (keyboardEventType == KeyboardEventType.DOWN)
        pressed[keyCode] = true;
    if (keyboardEventType == KeyboardEventType.UP)
    {
        pressed[keyCode] = false;

        if (grounded) 
        {
            moving = false;
            degeticaRb.angularVelocity = 0f;
            degeticaRb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        }
    }
}
```

Practically speaking, you may want to simply use `Input.GetKey`, `Input.GetKeyUp` and `Input.GetKeyDown` instead of managing the key state yourself.

Comment: is not work....KeyboardEventSystem is work exactly like Input....so I do not think that's the problem here

Comment: if you press D and spin, then moving becomes false when i release the keyboard but after that I can not press A until you press D again

Comment: yes, the bag was in my class....i use this: moving = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow);....and it work perfectly